# React navigation drawer navigator move main content when drawer open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to open drawer and move main content to side.

example like this

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you get it?? I'm having the same requirement. Couldnt find a solution

Answer (score 3):

In version 3.x of `react-navigation` you could use `drawerType: 'slide'`. See the following example:

```
const DrawerExample = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Inbox: {
      path: '/',
      screen: InboxStack,
    },
    Drafts: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: DraftsStack,
    },
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Drafts',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
    drawerType: 'slide'
  }
);
```

Notice the `createDrawerNavigator()` instead of `DrawerNavigator()`

Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/en/